# Postgres: Best way to move data from public schema of one DB to new schema of another DB

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, pg-dump

I am new to Postgres and just discovered that I cannot access data of different databases in one SQL query. And also learned the concept of schema in Postgres.

Now, I have two databases

db1 and db2

Both have tables with same name in their public schema.

Now, I want to create a new schema in db1 with name : new_schema

And move data from db2.public to db1.new_schema

What is the easiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is to rename schemas. However you must be sure you are a sole user of db1 database.

First, hide your schema public in db1:

```
alter schema public rename to original_public;
create schema public;
```

Next, do the backup and restore:

```
$ pg_dump --format custom --file "my_backup" --schema "public" "db2"
$ pg_restore --dbname "db1" "my_backup"
```

Finally, recreate appropriate schema names:

```
alter schema public rename to my_schema;
alter schema original_public rename to public;
```

Another option is to use [dblink.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/dblink.html) It enables accessing data of different databases.

Comment: Updating, about *dblink*, is better to use  [*postgres_fdw*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html). As guide say,  it "provides roughly the same functionality using a more modern and standards-compliant infrastructure".

Answer (score 4):

Export "public" from db2 (skipping grants and ownership):

```
pg_dump -xO -n public db2 > db2.sql
```

The exported file will set up the search path (somewhere near the top):

```
SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;
```

change it to:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS new_schema;
SET search_path = new_schema, pg_catalog;
```

Import to db1 as usual:

```
psql db1 < db2.sql
```

You'll probably want to move everything from public to a new schema in db1, first.

If the schema is already set up in db1, you can do the transfer in one go:

```
pg_dump -xO -n public db2 | sed 's/search_path = public/search_path = new_schema/' | psql db1
```

Wouldn't recommend that without a lot of testing, of course.

Comment: `/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_dump: invalid option -- '0'`